Preventing Port 10000 from Appearing in Webmin URL by Redirecting Traffic from Port 10000 to 443
I want to prevent port 10000 from appearing in the URL of the Webmin server by redirecting traffic using iptables rules, for example from port 10000 to port 443, so that the interface can be accessed with a URL like https://webminexemple.com
The following command:
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 10000

works for redirecting traffic. However, when navigating through the Webmin interface, port 10000 reappears in the URL. Port 443 is also used on the same server via Apache.
